# start Serial Number with 1 in EXcel With Diff Date

Tags: excel

I Have Data with date and i want to give serial no.

```
Date            ?(Formula)
08.06.2015        1
08.06.2015        2
08.06.2015        3
09.06.2015        1 
09.06.2015        2
10.06.2015        1
10.06.2015        2
```

I Tried `=if(a2=a1,b1+1,1)` but it is giving me circular reference error.

Comment: You need to further explain what field you are entering this formula in, if it's in B1 then that would explain your issue, Additionally, you should format your question so it is more readable, look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more help on formatting.

Answer (score 0):

In **B1** enter **1**
In **B2** enter:

```
=IF(A1=A2,B1+1,1)
```

and copy down.

**EDIT#1**

Here is a sample:

[image]

Comment: I don't think that will get it, I'm still not 100% sure what he is looking for but in your solution when you copy the formula down you end up with different expression and true parameter cells. So for example the second formula would read `=IF(A2=A3, B2+1,1)`. That's the correct action but it doesn't match his example (`1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2` not `1,2,3,1,2,1,2`)? Again not sure what this serial number/ formula field should be,